# How to change the color of vertical scroll bar on POLMO Free CSS Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

The vertical scrollbar is currently in red color, I want to change it to grey. How can I do that?
Please suggests me how to do these things.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you are using this `POLMO Free CSS Template` in SharePoint or not , but I will try to help you !

- Open the home page with any editor like Notepad  / Note++ or visual studio
- Find a div with ID `id="ascrail2000"` that have a custom style , change it's `background` property because it's the background of scroll to `background: rgb(252, 248, 227)`
- In child div change `background-color` property `background-color: rgb(167, 167, 168);`

**Final Div should look like :**

```
<div id="ascrail2000" class="nicescroll-rails" style="width: 7px; z-index: 99999; background: rgb(252, 248, 227); cursor: default; position: fixed; top: 0px; height: 100%; right: 0px; opacity: 0;"><div style="position: relative; top: 82px; float: right; width: 7px; height: 60px; background-color: rgb(167, 167, 168); border: none; background-clip: padding-box; border-radius: 0px;"></div></div>
```

**[OutPut:]**

[image]

**[Update]**

Add the following style to your home page within  tag

```
<style>

        #ascrail2000 {
        background: rgb(252, 248, 227) !important ;
        }

        #ascrail2000 div {

        background-color: rgb(167, 167, 168) !important;
        }

    </style>
```

Comment: Hi Qassas, Seem I cannot see this tag in html home page, only seen it on view source page. It seem embed by scrip. http://www.free-css.com/free-css-templates/page195/polmo

Comment: I have downloaded the template , and you are right , but i overrite it as mentioned in my updated answer :) , hope it helps you